# How to return a value from class in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have WCF C# class return two value to anther class , it is work fine but I need the same code in vb.net so I used convert C# to vb.net online site , the result 
the vb code :

```vb
<WebMethod(MessageName:="OpenAccount", Description:="this method create new account in the database"), _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(GetType(ContactResult))> _
Public Function OpenAccount(ByVal Num As String, ByVal Pass As String) As ContactResult
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cr As New ContactResult
    Try
        Dim data As String
        Dim openCon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MONZER\Desktop\Karary Web Site\WebApplication1\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Password", openCon)
        Dim saveStaff As String = "select Spec from Password where Num = @AndroidNum AND Pass = @AndroidPass"
        Dim querySaveStaff As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(saveStaff)
        querySaveStaff.Connection = openCon
        querySaveStaff.Parameters.Clear()
        querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AndroidNum", Num)
        querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AndroidPass", Pass)
        openCon.Open()
        querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ds.Clear()
        da.Fill(ds, "Password")
        data = ds.Tables("Password").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
        openCon.Close()
        cr.ErrorID = 0
        cr.ErrorMessage = "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"
        Return cr
    Catch ex As Exception
        cr.ErrorID = 1
        cr.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        Return cr
    End Try
End Function
```

return ErrorID and ErrorMessage to ContactResult class
the ContactResult vb:

```vb
Public Class ContactResult
    Public Property ErrorID As Integer
        Get
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ErrorMessage As String
        Get
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

but it is not working it just return the ErrorID without ErrorMessage ,it is show like this in browser:

```
<ContactResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

0

Comment: put a breakpoint on `Return cr` command and verify its properties before exiting the OpenAccount function

Comment: If the C# code works and the VB doesn't then you did something wrong in the conversion. Maybe showing us the code you're converting from would be a good idea too.

Comment: Incidentally, you need to dispose of `openCon` once you are finished with it. The easiest way for that to happen is to use a [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property handlers don't do anything. So ErrorID remains 0 (the default value of `Integer`) and ErrorMessage remains at `null` (the default value of `string`). Seems the converter changed your [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties) incorrectly:

```
public string PropertyName { get; set; }
```

to

```
Public Property PropertyName As String
    Get
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
    End Set
End Property
```

instead of

```
Public Property PropertyName As String
```

Try switching `ContactResult` to

```
Public Class ContactResult
    Public Property ErrorID As Integer
    Public Property ErrorMessage As String
End Class
```